# Enable/allow Proxy From Different Server With SSL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-proxy

I have a node.js app on server A (http://sub.domainA). My customer wants to use this solution without redirecting. The configuration in .htaccess for the node.js service on server A looks like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost:61361/$1 [P]
```

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://sub.domainA/$1 [P]
```

but I get a 403 Forbidden.

**Question 1 - Solved:**
How can I make my customers server access this node service?

EDIT:
Got this working already. It seemed the Proxy to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://sub.domainA/$1 [P]
```

did build a proxy not to the subdirectory on the server but instead to the html directory which is a sibling of the sub directory. So I ended up copying the .htaccess to the html folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost:61361/$1 [P]
```

**Question 2**
Will this work with https (SSL) connections too, if I store the certificates on both servers? How to store the certificate on server A.

Server B

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^serverB\.de
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://sub.serverA.de/$1 [P]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^serverB\.de
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://sub.serverA.de/$1 [P]
```

Server A

Already forwards http -> https